# SSC Single-Sign on options

Tags: single-sign-on, fortify

I have installed and HP SSC 4.30

I need to implement Single Sign on and my preferred options are

Crowd
OpenID
HTTP Header Value

I am not seeing any information on SSO options. I did see a sso.properties file, indicating SSC will use HTTP header value for authentication, but not sure how to set it up.

Appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks

S

Comment: I saw documentation on HTTP header based Single Sign on, and I think I can use it. However, documentation is not clear on how to set filterChain, e.g. if I press logout, I am not logged in automatically, so not sure how to intercept certain url patterns..

Comment: Contact Fortify Technical Support.